# How can I make so that every time outputted-item is outputted in the input field if its clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make so that every time something that has the class outputted-item, whenever it is clicked then the outputted item shall be in the input field, but at the same time I want it to get added not to get replaced since I am making a calculator?

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    const buttons = {
      delete: $("#delete"),
      divide: $("#divide"),
      one: $("#one"),
      two: $("#two"),
      three: $("#three"),
      four: $("#four"),
      five: $("#five"),
      six: $("#six"),
      seven: $("#seven"),
      eight: $("#eight"),
      nine: $("#nine"),
      multiplicate: $("#multiplicate"),
      minus: $("#minus"),
      equalSign: $("#equal"),
      plus: $("#plus"),
      inputfield: $("#inputfield")
    }

    let outputArray = document.querySelectorAll(".outputted-item");
    debugger;
    outputArray.forEach((output) => {
      output.addEventListener("click", () => {
        inputfield.innerHTML += output;
        console.log(output);
        debugger;
      })
    })

    console.log(outputArray);
```

```css
 /* general styling */

    * {
      outline: 0;
    }

    html {
      font-size: 62.5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /* body */

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.835), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89)), url(/img/desktop-pc-1920x1080-thumbnail_00242.jpg);
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }


    /* the calculator */

    .container {
      height: 40rem;
      width: 40rem;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.664), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.664), rgba(53, 53, 158, 0.637), rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.657), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.664));
      display: grid;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30%;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      left: 40.5%;
      grid-gap: 1rem;
      box-shadow: 0rem 1.3rem 2rem rgb(0, 0, 0);
      padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
      border-radius: 1.5rem;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-items: center;
      transition: all .5s;
    }

    .item {
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 0rem .05rem 1.5rem black;
      border-radius: .8rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 2rem;
      transition: all .3s;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 3rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .item-multiplication {
      grid-column: 4 / 5;
      grid-row: 4 / 5;
    }

    .item-equalsign {
      grid-column: 3 / 4;
      grid-row: 4 / 5;
    }

    .item-delete {
      grid-row: 4 / 5;
      grid-column: 1 / 3;
      padding: 2rem 4rem;
    }

    .container:hover {
      transform: translate(0, -2rem) scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }

    .item:hover {
      transform: translate(0, -1rem) scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }

    .item:active {
      padding: 1.5rem;
    }


    /* output of the calculator */

    .inputfield {
      position: absolute;
      left: 43.5%;
      top: 15%;
      padding: 3rem 6rem;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      border-radius: 2rem;
      background: rgb(13, 78, 78);
      box-shadow: 0rem .7rem 2rem black;
    }

    .inputfield::placeholder {
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- output of the calculator -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Calccy" class="inputfield" id="inputfield">

    <!-- the calculator -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="one">1</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="two">2</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="three">3</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="plus">+</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="four">4</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="five">5</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="six">6</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="minus">-</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="seven">7</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="eight">8</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="nine">9</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item" id="divide">/</div>
      <div class="item outputted-item item-multiplication" id="outputted-item multiplicate">x</div>
      <div class="item item-equalsign" id="equal">=</div>
      <div class="item item-delete" id="delete">DEL</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problem areas I found:

You try to change your `#inputfield` element with by setting `.innerHTML`  instead of `.value`. And you try to access it as if it was defined globally, but the element should be accessed through `buttons.inputfield`?

The value that you want to update the input field with, is the *content* of the `.outputted-item`, not the element itself. So here I think you want to use `output.innerHTML` instead of just `output`.

```
outputArray.forEach((output) => {
      output.addEventListener("click", () => {
        buttons.inputfield.value += output.innerHTML;
      })
    })
```

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const buttons = {
  delete: $("#delete"),
  divide: $("#divide"),
  one: $("#one"),
  two: $("#two"),
  three: $("#three"),
  four: $("#four"),
  five: $("#five"),
  six: $("#six"),
  seven: $("#seven"),
  eight: $("#eight"),
  nine: $("#nine"),
  multiplicate: $("#multiplicate"),
  minus: $("#minus"),
  equalSign: $("#equal"),
  plus: $("#plus"),
  inputfield: $("#inputfield")
}

let outputArray = document.querySelectorAll(".outputted-item");

outputArray.forEach((output) => {
  output.addEventListener("click", () => {
    buttons.inputfield.value += output.innerHTML;
    console.log(buttons.inputfield.innerHTML);
  })
})

console.log(outputArray);
```

```css
/* general styling */

* {
  outline: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* body */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.835), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89)), url(/img/desktop-pc-1920x1080-thumbnail_00242.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}


/* the calculator */

.container {
  height: 40rem;
  width: 40rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.664), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.664), rgba(53, 53, 158, 0.637), rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.657), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.664));
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  left: 40.5%;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0rem 1.3rem 2rem rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0rem .05rem 1.5rem black;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-multiplication {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.item-equalsign {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.item-delete {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
}

.container:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -2rem) scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.item:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -1rem) scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.item:active {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}


/* output of the calculator */

.inputfield {
  position: absolute;
  left: 43.5%;
  top: 15%;
  padding: 3rem 6rem;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background: rgb(13, 78, 78);
  box-shadow: 0rem .7rem 2rem black;
}

.inputfield::placeholder {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- output of the calculator -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Calccy" class="inputfield" id="inputfield">

<!-- the calculator -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="two">2</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="three">3</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="plus">+</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="four">4</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="five">5</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="six">6</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="minus">-</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="seven">7</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="eight">8</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="nine">9</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item" id="divide">/</div>
  <div class="item outputted-item item-multiplication" id="outputted-item multiplicate">x</div>
  <div class="item item-equalsign" id="equal">=</div>
  <div class="item item-delete" id="delete">DEL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you btw, im currently refrshing my js skills, making small games quizzes and taking an es6 course just to refresh it. i thank you doe for your time taken

Comment: No problem. Cool, sounds like a good plan! Since you seem like you're pretty new here on Stackoverflow, maybe you don't know the "rules" or the "etiquette" yet:

If my answer helped you, there is an up-vote arrow to show gratitude. If the answer solved your problem or answered your question you may mark the answer as "correct".  That's how this community works, people ask questions and  they get rewarded by getting  help/answers. The ones offering help and/or answers get upvotes etc.